# React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Can someone explain the difference between

```html
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

and

```html
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

I don't know the meaning of `exact`.

Comment: The answers are all great. However one may get a doubt like "Why can not we have <code>exact</code> for all the routes then?" Imagine a URL that is something like this. <code> https://yourreactwebsite.com/getUsers/userId=? </code> This is an example where the user's ID will be dynamically fed in the URL and so we can not go with <code>exact</code> prop in your Router here.

Answer (score 542, accepted):

In this example, nothing really. The `exact` param comes into play when you have multiple paths that have similar names:

For example, imagine we had a `Users` component that displayed a list of users. We also have a `CreateUser` component that is used to create users. The url for `CreateUsers` should be nested under `Users`. So our setup could look something like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
  <Route path="/users/create" component={CreateUser} />
</Switch>
```

Now the problem here, when we go to `http://app.com/users` the router will go through all of our defined routes and return the FIRST match it finds. So in this case, it would find the `Users` route first and then return it. All good.

But, if we went to `http://app.com/users/create`, it would again go through all of our defined routes and return the FIRST match it finds. React router does partial matching, so `/users` partially matches `/users/create`, so it would incorrectly return the `Users` route again!

The `exact` param disables the partial matching for a route and makes sure that it only returns the route if the path is an EXACT match to the current url.

So in this case, we should add `exact` to our `Users` route so that it will only match on `/users`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
  <Route path="/users/create" component={CreateUser} />
</Switch>
```

[The docs explain `exact` in detail and give other examples.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

**UPDATE 2023** as pointed out by user [smit-gabani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19144656/smit-gabani)

The new version of react - v6 does not support exact anymore.

As stated in their documentation:

> You don't need to use an exact prop on anymore. This is because all
> paths match exactly by default. If you want to match more of the URL
> because you have child routes use a trailing * as in

Comment: "But, if we went to http://app.com/users/create, it would again go through all of our defined routes and return the FIRST match it finds." - in fact it will return all the Routes for which it found a match (full or partial). The behavior described by @Chase DeAnda will happen only if the the <Route>'s are enclosed by a <Switch> tag.

Comment: `exact` should be the default in my opinion

Comment: What about if we have each route definition in different components, I mean `/admin//users` in Admin component, and `/admin/users/create` in the Root component??? I'm currently have this situation and the typical `exact` solution do not work properly.

Comment: I think this behavior only works if both routes are in the same level of its Switch parent (or component)

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez The highest level route definition will always win. So in the root if you have `/admin/users/create`, router will select that route instead of `/admin/users` which is nested in the Admin component because the Admin component was never rendered.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda what I need is exactly the opposite. Maybe I should write a new answer on SO to clarify my situation and get properly answers.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Unless <Switch> is used, all the matching routes are returned. The very purpose of switch is to render only the first <Route> or <Redirect> that matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have nested routes and they were always returning the first route as you said. This one was working: `<PrivateRoute path="/:unit/:department" component={Department} />` but this one wasn't: `<PrivateRoute path="/:unit/:department/main-admins" component={MainManagers} />`. So I added `exact` to the firts one and it worked :)

Answer (score 33):

In short, if you have multiple routes defined for your app's routing, enclosed with `Switch` component like this;

```
<Switch>

  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/detail" component={Detail} />

  <Route exact path="/functions" component={Functions} />
  <Route path="/functions/:functionName" component={FunctionDetails} />

</Switch>
```

Then you have to put `exact` keyword to the Route which it's path is also included by another Route's path. For example home path `/` is included in all paths so it needs to have `exact` keyword to differentiate it from other paths which start with `/`. The reason is also similar to `/functions` path. If you want to use another route path like `/functions-detail` or `/functions/open-door` which includes `/functions` in it then you need to use `exact` for the `/functions` route.

Comment: Actually the second part explains it. Let's say if you have 2 routes like `/motor` and `/motorbike` then you need to put `exact` to the route with path `/motor`.  Otherwise, both `/motor` and `/motorbike` routes pick up the component with path `/motor`.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool

**exact: bool**

When true, will only match if the path matches the `location.pathname` exactly.

```
**path**    **location.pathname**   **exact**   **matches?**

/one        /one/two                true        no
/one        /one/two                false       yes
```

Answer (score 8):

**If you have multiple routes defined for your app's routing, enclosed with Routes components that have similar names we might get unpredicted behavior.**

For example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
  <Route path="/users/create" component={CreateUser} />
</Routes>
```

Might give you some errors when you go to route

```
/users/create
```

Because as soon as react finds a root that matches with the regex user* it will redirect you to that route that is /users

Using exact like this

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
  <Route path="/users/create" component={CreateUser} />
</Switch>
```

**The new version of react - v6 does not support `exact` anymore.**

As stated in their documentation:

> **You don't need to use an exact prop on  anymore. This is because all paths match exactly by default.** If you want to match more of the URL because you have child routes use a trailing * as in `<Route path="users/*">`

Answer (score 1):

The ***exact*** prop in  is used to ensure that the specified route matches exactly with the current location.

**Route exact path="/":**

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

In this, the Home component will only be rendered when the path is exactly "/" and not for paths like "/about" or "/contact".

**Route path="/":**

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

In this, the Home component will be rendered not only for the exact path "/" but also for any other path that starts with "/".

Answer (score -2):

By using exact, you can make sure that the contents of the homepage component will not appear on the other pages.

**This is the scenario without using exact:**

HOMEPAGE

Location: /

```
-----------------
homepage content
-----------------
```

SECOND PAGE

Location: /second-page

```
-----------------
homepage content
-----------------
-----------------
second content
-----------------
```

==========================================

**Using exact:**

HOMEPAGE

Location: /

```
-----------------
homepage content
-----------------
```

SECOND PAGE

Location: /second-page

```
-----------------
second content
-----------------
```

Answer (score -9):

**Please try this.**

```
       <Router>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/news" component={NewsFeed} />
          </div>
        </Router>
```

Comment: Please explain your proposed solution.

Answer (score -10):

**The shortest answer is**

Please try this.

```
<switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
   <Route path="/about" component={About} />
   <Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />
 </switch>
```

Comment: This does basically nothing to explain the meaning of the `exact` attribute/prop, and thus is surely not an "answer". You should try to address the question actually being asked rather than to give a solution to a problem which you are not sure OP actually has.