# Issues with nesting routes inside my main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building my first React app from scratch using React BoilerPlate for practice.  I'm running into issues with my routes.

```html
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

import ApplicationsPage from '../ApplicationsPage'
import CompanyApplicantsPage from '../CompanyApplicantsPage'
import CompanyJobsPage from '../CompanyJobsPage'
import CompanyLocationsPage from '../CompanyLocationsPage'
import CompanyPage from '../CompanyPage'
import CompanyRecruitersPage from '../CompanyRecruitersPage'
import CompanySettingsPage from '../CompanySettingsPage'
import EditResumePage from '../EditResumePage'
import EditCompanyPage from '../EditCompanyPage'
import EditJobPage from '../EditJobPage'
import EditProfilePage from '../EditProfilePage'
import JobPage from '../JobPage'
import JobsPage from '../JobsPage'
import NewCompanyPage from '../NewCompanyPage'
import NewJobPage from '../NewJobPage'
import NewProfilePage from '../NewProfilePage'
import NotFoundPage from '../NotFoundPage/Loadable'
import Main from '../Main'
import ProfilePage from '../ProfilePage'
import ProfileSettingsPage from '../ProfileSettingsPage'
import ProfilesPage from '../ProfilesPage'
import EditLocationPage from '../EditLocationPage'

export default function App() {
  const history = createBrowserHistory()

  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route component={Main}>
        <Route path="/jobs" component={JobsPage} />
        <Route path="/jobs/new" component={NewJobPage} />
        <Route path="/jobs/:job_id" component={JobPage} />
        <Route path="/jobs/:job_id/edit" component={EditJobPage} />
        <Route path="/profiles" component={ProfilesPage} />
        <Route path="/profiles/new" component={NewProfilePage} />
        <Route path="/profiles/:profile_id" component={ProfilePage} />
        <Route path="/profiles/:profile_id/edit" component={EditProfilePage} />
        <Route path="/profiles/:profile_id/edit_resume" component={EditResumePage} />
        <Route path="/profiles/:profile_id/applications" component={ApplicationsPage} />
        <Route path="/profiles/:profile_id/settings" component={ProfileSettingsPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/new" component={NewCompanyPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id" component={CompanyPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id/edit" component={EditCompanyPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id/jobs" component={CompanyJobsPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id/locations" component={CompanyLocationsPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id/locations/location_id" component={EditLocationPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id/recruiters" component={CompanyRecruitersPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id/settings" component={CompanySettingsPage} />
        <Route path="/companies/:company_id/applicants" component={CompanyApplicantsPage} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Essentially, my Main component has all my main content that I want to wrap around the whole site (navbar, body styling etc.).  And any component rendered inside.

Each of these other components have a form on them, and when I go to any one of these paths I only see my Main content, not my forms. What am I doing wrong.

This is the only error I have in the console:

> You should not use  and  in the same
>   route;  will be ignored

Which seems like it could be related, but I seem to find a lot of examples of people doing it this way and I can't seem to make it work any way I try.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "exact" in the route component.
Use 
`<Route exact path="/jobs/new" component={NewJobPage} />`
to go to that particular page instead of `<Route path="/jobs/new" component={NewJobPage} />`

Check [React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)
for more understanding.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That didn't seem to work, unfortunately.  Now I am also getting a new error: 

Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.

Comment: I believe this new error is due to unavailability of path in " <Route component={NotFoundPage} />" and " <Route component={Main}>". Also if your entry point is the main component, direct it to the home page,  <Route path="/" component={Main}>