# React router: Route not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-v4

I am in a component whose URL is

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/profile/timeline/abcd
```

and the route is set up as

```
<Route path="/dashboard/profile/:screenId/:userId" component={this.Routing}/>
```

When I go to a different profile for e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/profile/timeline/xyz
```

It is not routing but the url is changing

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: show us the other routes + changed url.

Answer (score 0):

replace `component={this.Routing}` with `component={Routing}`

```
<Route exact path="/dashboard/profile/:screenId/:userId" component={Routing}/>
```

[React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)

if your problem not resolve use `Switch` 
I have this problem too and i resolve with `Switch`

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
.
.
.
.

        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact key="1" path="/dashboard/profile/:screenId/:userId" component={Routing}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```