# How to use routes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I created a web-app that uses reactjs. Now the basics of the app are :

Create Topics/Sub topics.
Display them (this uses react )
Now 2nd task is explained as :-

Show all the topics/sub topics list.
Clicking any of them sends json req and the data is recieved and displayed.
Now I want to share the topic with link , however on clicking any of the topic only one elemnt of the html renders and the url remains the same.

So this is what i want to do -

On clicking , send json req and recieve data ( done )
Change the url ( I want to know if it is possible using the same react page? )

How can I use Routes in the following code ?

Part 1 :- Deals with recents posts
Part 2 :- Deals with the Headings or Topic names
Part 3 :- Deals with Sub topics
Part 4 :- Deals with showing the Article from the chosen topic and sub topic.

Now its obvious that though the article is displayed , the link / url of the page will never change. However it makes it hard to share the articles. Thus I want to know how to apply the routes in this case ?

```
render() {
  var lists = this.state.list;
  var lists2 = this.state.list2;
  var aname = this.state.article.name;
  var date = this.state.article.date;
  var lists3 = this.state.listrec;

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div id="recentsbar" className="col-md-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-9">
            <div>
              <div style={{ display: this.state.hide2 }}>
                <h2>
                  <b> Recents </b>
                </h2>
                <div
                  className="lds-ellipsis"
                  style={{ display: this.state.load2 }}
                >
                  <div />
                  <div />
                  <div />
                  <div />
                </div>
                <div id="subl">
                  {lists3.map(number => (
                    <Item3 name={number} show={this.rec.bind(this)} />
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-8">
        <div style={{ display: this.state.hide }}>
          <h1 style={{ marginLeft: 6 + "em" }}>
            <b> Subjects List </b>
          </h1>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <ul style={{ marginTop: 1 + "em" }} /*className="list-group"*/>
                <div
                  className="lds-ellipsis"
                  style={{ display: this.state.load }}
                >
                  <div />
                  <div />
                  <div />
                  <div />
                </div>
                {lists.map(number => (
                  <Item name={number} hide={this.hide.bind(this)} />
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8">
          <div style={{ display: this.state.show }}>
            <h1 style={{ marginLeft: 6 + "em" }}>
              <b> {this.state.selsub} </b>
            </h1>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-auto" style={{ marginLeft: 6 + "em" }}>
                <ul
                  style={{ marginTop: 1 + "em" }}
                  className="list-group art"
                >
                  <div
                    className="lds-ellipsis"
                    style={{ display: this.state.load }}
                  >
                    <div />
                    <div />
                    <div />
                    <div />
                  </div>
                  {lists2.map(number => (
                    <Item2 name={number} hide2={this.hide2.bind(this)} />
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style={{ display: this.state.showarticle }}>
          <div className="lds-ellipsis" style={{ display: this.state.load }}>
            <div />
            <div />
            <div />
            <div />
          </div>
          <div className="arthead"> {aname} </div>
          <div style={{ float: "right", opacity: 0.5 }}>
            Updated on: {date}{" "}
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              marginLeft: 1 + "em",
              lineHeight: 2 + "em",
              marginTop: 4 + "em"
            }}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.article.body }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: To change the current path you could just use `<Redirect>` from react-router-dom package. Take a deeper look in the oficial docs from react-training's github page.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into react-router's `Switch` and react-router-dom's `Route` Components.
For instance the following jsx:

```
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Switch } from 'react-router';
class YourComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    exact
                    render={
                        () => (
                           <h1>root content</h1>
                           <Link to="/content1">content1</Link>
                        )
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path="/content1"
                    exact
                    render={
                        () => (
                           <h1>content 1</h1>
                           <Link to="/">root</Link>
                        )
                    }
                />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

`Route` allows conditional rendering based on the URL.

`Switch` ensures the first matching Route only will be rendered (actually what's returned by the render prop of the Route component).

For all of this to work, remember that a Router component from react router must be an ancestor of YourComponent.

If you want to trigger an SPA navigation after an event, or during a callback, you have to use the `withRouter` HOC from react-router.
StackOverflow thread explaining how it works: [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

I also suggest you look into react-router-redux for redux integration of react-router. It offers the `push` action to navigate to another route.

References:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

[React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-redux

Comment: Thnx for the info. I had a doubt on import. ..... actually i am using react-router script (online uploaded) in my html as <script > tag . Now I want to use routes. I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Simple react routing example, hope it will make you undrestand routing in react.
https://github.com/shivakumaraswamy/reactjs/tree/master/ReacRouting

Comment: Thnx for the info. I had a doubt on import. ..... actually i am using react-router script (online uploaded) in my html as <script > tag . Now I want to use routes. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Which version of react router you are included in script?