# Two pages overlapping each other

Tags: reactjs

Two Pages(Products & Edit Product page) overlapping each other after clicking edit button. Instead of redirect to edit page, it is coming under the current page.

Here is my file contents. **https://codesandbox.io/s/mmwqz8lz8p**

[image: Here is my file contents.]

Answer (score 2):

Use `exact` in products route.

Because product edit path/link `/products/:id` is sub-link of product link `/products`. When you set path without `exact` and go to product edit link `/products/:id` it contain path for product `/products` and product edit `/products/:id` both. Then why when you go to product edit page both routes is working and `products` and  `editProduct` both component is showing.

To fix this you have to use `exact` attribute true for product route. Just like following

```
<Route exact path='/products' component={products}/>
```

Comment: What's the need?

Comment: Edited answer. If you like learn more about `exact` attribute  [read this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path.)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you use Switch Component in your code like

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
      <div className="App">
        <Route path='/' exact={true} component={loginscreen}/>
        <Route path='/users' exact={true} component={users}/>
        <Route path='/users/:id' component={userEdit}/>
        <Route path='/products' component={products}/>
        <Route path='/products/:id' component={editProduct}/>
        <Route path='/addproducts' component={addProduct}/>
        <Route path='/album' component={album}/>
        <Route path='/main' component={main}/>
      </div>
   </Switch>
 </Router>
```

The behaviour that you describe would be different from what you describe in your question. `Switch` component matches the first Route and skips the rest. Also the way React router match works is that any Route path will also match its Prefix Routes, for example, `/products/:id` will also match `/products` and without the use of `Switch` all matches will be rendered.

As per your above configuration, `/products/:id` will also render `/products` page only. In order for it to work correctly, just reverse the order of your Routes,

```
 <Switch>
      <div className="App">
        <Route path='/' exact={true} component={loginscreen}/>
        <Route path='/users' exact={true} component={users}/>
        <Route path='/users/:id' component={userEdit}/>
        <Route path='/products/:id' component={editProduct}/>
        <Route path='/products' component={products}/>
        <Route path='/addproducts' component={addProduct}/>
        <Route path='/album' component={album}/>
        <Route path='/main' component={main}/>
      </div>
   </Switch>
```

**P.S.** As a rule, all prefix Routes must be written later in the order.