# How to use handle 404 error with react-router on django projects

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router

I am currently building a django-react web apps, I am wondering how do I handle my 404 error on react-router and not with django side, this is my code which 404 error will be routed on django server side...

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
re_path(r'^api/', include(urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


routes = getattr(settings, 'REACT_ROUTES', [])
# urlpatterns += [url(r'^', 
TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
urlpatterns += [url(r'^(%s)?$' % '|'.join(routes),TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would have done:

First define a url from django with regex pattern which accepts anything:

```
url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(), name="home")  # This is the view which servers the react application
```

And add this path at the bottom of the urlpatterns.

Second, add new router in React App:

```
<Route component={NotFoundComponent} />  // This component is for showing 404 page.
```

For rest of the routers should have [exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path).

You can see [this tutorial](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-handling-404-pages/) on how to implement 404 page in react.

Comment: i have tested your solution , but it doesn't route to my react-router 404 error page. it shows my home page for example suppose localhost:8000 is my home page component , when i tried localhost:8000/1 it doesn't route to my component instead it give me 200 status code and showed my home page.
[18/Dec/2018 06:41:39] "GET /5 HTTP/1.1" 200 2374
[18/Dec/2018 06:41:39] "GET /static/js/main.67b00170.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[18/Dec/2018 06:41:40] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 93

Comment: my react component is below 
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={MainPage} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>

Comment: I think you need to use exact here. Check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path

Comment: thank you so much, i have been able to make my 404 error routes on react-router, it seems like my django rest api need to request with make sure of the link end with '/'