# having issues in understand path passed to react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How does the two path differ . I tried going through the docs of react router but it still creates confusion .
First one is

```
   <Route
    path="/cricket/:description/:id"
    component={xyz}
  />
 and another is 
  <Route 
   exact
   path="/cricket"
   component={xyz1}
 />
```

I see that the first Route is mentioned in App.js .It leads to confusion as which one got executed and how ?

Comment: The first path has actual [URL parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) which you can access later

Comment: First is a route which contains parameters. So for example this routes to `mydomain.com/cricket/points/3`. These parameters can be used in the component. Second route is just to `mydomain.com/cricket`

Comment: Here's a nice thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path

Answer (score 0):

Router will render both componenets if path is something like `/cricket/foo/123` because it matches both pattern.

If you want only one to render you have to use `exact` prop like

`<Route exact path="/cricket"
   component={xyz1}
 />`

Comment: Hey Amit ,I understand exact thing .I wanted explanation on other things .