# React router4: one of the Route not hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a component with below routes

```
<Route key= 'project-data' path='project/:id/detail/project-data/' render={ProjectDataView}>
<Route key= 'task' path='project/:id/detail/project-task/' render={renderForm2}>
<Route key= 'activity' path='project/:id/detail/project-activity/' render={renderForm3}>
<Route key= 'milestone' path='project/:id/detail/project-milestone/' render={renderForm4}>
<Route key= 'project' path='project/:id/detail/project-data/update/' render={UpdateProjectView}>
```

There is one button in `ProjectDataView` to `project/:id/detail/project-data/update/` which should go to UpdateProjectView, however, it does not work.

The weird thing is if I change the **last Route's path** to `project/:id/detail/project-update/` and the button to destination to `project/:id/detail/project-update/`, then it's all good. As I only change the path so I am guessing it's something Route does which I do not know.

I am new to react-route. I am using react-route 4.

Comment: Your first and last route are same. So it always picks up first route. Use exact for last route. Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path

Comment: @tarzenchugh thanks and the link you provided explains details

Comment: wrap in a Switch, using exact as the previous one and move the last to above the first then your problem will be solved