# React Navbar issue with link locaton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a navbar component which changes the link on a specific button based on the current URL.

This is what I have so far:
Navbar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const testfun = () => {
        if (/\/test\/[0-9]+/.test(window.location.href)) {
            let id;
            const match = /(?:\/)(\d+)(?:\/)?/g.exec(window.location.href);
            console.log(match);
            if (match) {
                id = "/" + match[1] + "/edit";
            } else {
                id = "/test";
            }
            return (
                <Button component={Link} to={`/test${id}`} color="inherit">
                    Test2
                </Button>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Button component={Link} to="/test" color="inherit">
                    Test2
                </Button>
            );
        }
    };

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button component={Link} to="/" color="inherit">
                            Home
            </Button>
            <Button component={Link} to="/test" color="inherit">
                            test
            </Button>
            {
               testfun ()
            }
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">

                <Switch>
                    //Different routes
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>

           )
}

export default App;
```

The idea is the following - if the user is on `/test/123`, where `123` is any number page and clicks the button Test2 which is rendered by the `testfun` function, it should get redirected to the `/test/123/edit` page. If the user is on any other page and clicks the same button, it should get redirected to `/test` page.

The implementation above renders the button `Test2` but it always points to `/test` regardless of the page the user is on.

Comment: Can I have an example of match? like what do u have if /test/123 is given?

Comment: @TsungJuiWang if `/test/123/` is the current url, it should get redirected to `/test/123/edit` after hitting the button

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49162311/7913142

Comment: @CuongTranDuc has nothing to do with exath paths.

Comment: The problem is that match is always empty, so the regular expression does not work.

Comment: @TsungJuiWang I've been thinking how to make it execute the function and partially/fully re-render the Navbar on URL change but haven't come up with a way to do so

Comment: React-router internally puts two objects called match and location, taking advantage of them will solve your problem gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work by wrapping by Navbar in `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`

Here is my Navbar.js after the fix:

```
function Navbar(props) {
   //same logic as above
}
export default withRouter(Navbar);
```

Now I have access to history, location and match object.