# react-router routes <Link> v5

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to understand nested react routes. My current issue is that my link outputs undefined and also renders the component on the same view instead of loading just that component view.

Events.js

```
const data = {
   "events":[
      {
         "id":"1234",
         "name":"Meetup",
         "description":"Tech meetup"
      },
      {
         "id":"34234",
         "name":"Test",
         "description":"Events"
      }
   ]
}

{data.events.map(event => (
    <Link to={`/events/${data.events.id}`}>
        <EventCard data={event} />
    </Link>
))}

<Switch>
  <Route path={`/events/:eventId`}  render={(props) => <Event {...props}  />}/>
</Switch>
```

How can I render the Event component when a user has clicked one of the event card. I can currently load both components on the same page but that is not my desired output. The expected path should be:

Expected:

Render  only

Current:

Renders  &  on same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you have got a problem here,

```
<Link to={`/events/${data.events.id}`}>
```

Since you are already mapping event object from data array, iterator event already holds event data. So you should change it like this;

```
<Link to={`/events/${event.id}`}>
```

Also I'd strongly recommend to use 'exact' prop in your routes for routing multiple endpoints from same root like this.

```
<Route exact path={`/events/:eventId`}  render={(props) => <Event {...props}  />}/>
```

See here for further information. [Difference between exact path and path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)

Comment: I think my issue is that once I click on a Card the url is events/1234 however both my Events component and Event component both render on the same page. I would like to render only Event once I click on a card

Comment: I did and it does work however the Events and Event component are loaded on both pages. OnClick i would like to render <Event> not <Events><Event>. Would it an issue on the WebApp level? always rendering Events?

Comment: Maybe you can try using a wrapper for <Event> component such as <EventWrapper event={data} /> that renders <Event> by prop. At the moment, I don't know your architecture but you can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` param to your event endpoint:

```
 <Route path="/events/:id?" component={Event} />
```

Then in the `Event` you can check if `id` is present via `props.match.params.id`.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of the event Component as currently I am only rendering <h1>

Comment: I think that actually could be your `EventCard` component.