# React nested routing problem (cannot displayed the child component)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to react development. And I want to implement the routing mechanism in my page. 
For example, there's  component contains routes with the `<Home />` and `<Login />` component.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `<Home />` component contains a `<Navbar />` and a `<Switch />` with two `<Route />`:

Home.js

```
function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={`/home`}>
                        <Menu />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path={`/home/temperature`}>
                        <div>temperature</div>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, I defined the `<Link />` in the `<Menu />` component as below:

```
function Menu() {
    return (
        <div>
            <li>
                <Link to={`/home/temperature`}>temperature child page</Link>
            </li>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Originally, the page would displayed the `<Home />` component with `<Menu />` and `<div> temperature </div>` 
I expected that when I clicked the link (`<Link to={`/home/temperature`}>temperature child page</Link>`) then it would replace the `<Menu />` component with the only the `<div>temperature</div>` (Dispalyed the `<Navbar/>` and `<div>temperature</div>`, but it could not display anything. 
How should I correct it?

---

**Solution**:

I finally figure out why I cannot get child component in my js script.

Firstly, I need to wrap the `<Switch>` with `<Router>` in `<App>` component.
Then, by reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path) , I realized that I should not specify the `exact` in `<Route path="/home">` to make sure that the nested route can work as well.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: why don't you just define your routes globally? There is no need to put another switch inside your <Home> component. Just put it all into your <App>

Comment: @TimGerhard, I followed the example from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting, I thought putting the switch inside the <Home> component is a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

simple routing

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={"/home"} exact component={Home} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

nested routing

```
<Router>
     <Switch>
         <Route path={"/home"} exact component={Home}
             <Rout path={"/temperature"} exact component={Temperature} />
         </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

`