# Electron React Boilerplate not navigating to new Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I decided to give electron-react-boilerplate (https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/) a try for a project where I MUST use Electron.

The framework seems promising until it doesn't work, The Routing seems to be broken, yet it doesn't render any error message. The console shows the Redux action on the Routing library working fine, yet the corresponding Component doesn't show.

I updated the Routes.tsx file with the new route. I copied the Home components and renamed it to Hello.
When I click on the link, nothing happens.

Has anyone worked with this framework and have an example of more than two routes? Also, has anyone used this in Production? The fact that their Issues on Github are sitting there for the longest is a concern. I asked for help in a Community Chat that they have and no one has ever responded. All they have is 40 members.

Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer to my problem in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404717/react-router-dom-route-paths-defined-behind-not-working Thanks!