# Nested React Router path to n level

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component called `<TaskView>` that renders some info about a specific task. My tasks are nested so that I would be able to navigate like so `/task1/task1-1/task1-1-1...`  and so on for N (indefinitely).
How should I write a path that would resolve this url ?
To write a path for level 1 nested I would do: `<Route path="/task/:p1" component={taskView} />`, for level 2 I would do `<Route path="/task/:p1/:p2" component={taskView} />`   I don't know how deep the task structure would be, so how would I write a path for an undefined number of parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

ReactRouter has a notion of non exact matches. It will attempt to find the best match so you don't need to define all these subroutes to mount the same components.

[React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)

So actually you should be able to do

```
<Route path="/task/:p1" component={taskView} />
```

just fine.

Comment: I also need to know which task needs to be displayed, so I need at least the last element or parameter. How could I get that properly ? A way to do it would be ```location.pathname.split('/')``` and then get the last element, but that seems a little bit hacky.