# what is the way of making multiple routes with the same initiate paths in react

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in react js

```
const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
            <Route path="/posts/new" component={New} />
        </div>
    </Router>
)
ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'))
```

when I try to write localhost/posts or localhost/posts/new , the same components called .
I know that this behaviour occurred because I have "posts" in both routes . 
any solution for my problem , I need "posts" in both routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution:

Put your `/posts/new` route **before** your `/posts` route. React does partial matching starting with your first route. So `/posts/*` will always match with `/posts` (unless you use the `exact` prop!)

Better solution:

Use the `exact` prop on your `/posts` route to only accept requests to `/posts`. See my answer here for more details on how `exact` works in React: [React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path/49162423#49162423)