# Can't render only one Route in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I made a router, but upon request /user/add, both components are rendered.
I need to only display the UserAdd component.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="users/add" component={UserAdd} />
  <Route exact path="users/:id" component={UserPreview} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: If you have rendered the routes in a `Switch` as in the question, `exact` is not required, can you recheck if this indeed the configuration being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `exact` to route,

```
<Route exact path="/users/add" component={UserAdd} />
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: I added `exact` to both Route. But when we turn to /users/add, both UserAdd and UserPreview are rendered.

Comment: @Maks Endless , could you please share what was the problem? I think it was missing `/`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`exact` keyword is used only when you want to render a component when there is an exact match of route.

When you have multiple routes then use `exact` to visit specific page.

```
<Route exact path="/users/add" component={UserAdd} />
```

For better understanding between `<Route exact path="/" />` and `<Route path="/" />`

check [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)