# react routing a no match found page

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
 <div>
               <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/signup" component={Register}/>
                    <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
                    <Route path="/resetpassword" component={ResetPassword}/>
                    <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Feed}/>
                    <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
               </Switch>
            </div>
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route,Redirect} from "react-router-dom";


const PrivateRoute = ({component:Component, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
         props.user? 
        <Component {...props}/> : 
        <Redirect to="/login"/>
    )}/>
);


export default PrivateRoute;
```

So every route is working, except from when I type a url that doesn't exist. Whenever I do that, then it redirects me to the login page. Is there a way to stop the PrivateRoute from preventing the auto redirect when a page is not found?

thanks in advance for all the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with  `exact path`

```
   <Switch>
       <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
       <Route path="/signup" component={Register}/>
       <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
       <Route path="/resetpassword" component={ResetPassword}/>
       <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword}/>
       <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Feed}/>
       <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
   </Switch>
```

Comment: here is a link that explains this concept well :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path

Comment: Thanks for the resources and the help and sure, how do I validate the answer?

Comment: Ok i validated for you!!