# How to default to a route based on a URL parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a routing setup where if only 1 param is given, i.e /:id I want the router to always redirect to /:id/overview.

For example, if the user goes to /hello, I want them to be redirected to /hello/overview.

I've tried doing this like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={NoParam} />
  <Redirect from="/:section" to="/:section/overview" />
  <Route exact path="/:section/:pageName" component={GeneralOverviewPage} />   
</Switch>
```

This causes an infinite re-render. I'm not sure how to achieve this redirect, and would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

EDIT=======

Now trying to do it like this:

```
const GeneralOverviewPage: FC<RouteComponentProps<GeneralOverviewPageProps>> = (
  props
) => {
  console.log(props);
  return !props.match.params.pageName ? (
    <Redirect to={props.match.params.section + '/overview'} />
  ) : (
    <h1>{props.match.params.pageName}</h1>
  );
};

export default GeneralOverviewPage;
```

and

```
<Route path="/:section" component={GeneralOverviewPage} />
      <Route path="/:section/:pageName" component={GeneralOverviewPage} />
```

This means that /hello is now redirecting to /hello/hello/overview....

Comment: Not an expert on React so forgive me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't you want to add the exact keyword to the Redirect?

Comment: Also; auth issues can cause these sorts of issues as well

Comment: Hi guys, I want to programmatically use the section that is passed to the route

Comment: @Daniel, I've tried something else (I'll edit the og post) but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will Help You around for understanding!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={
                () => console.log("Hi")
            } />
            <Redirect exact from="/:section" to="/:section/overview" render={
                () => console.log("Hi 1")
            } />
            <Route exact path="/:section/:pageName" render={
                () => console.log("Hi 2")
            } />
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is now working for me, and I have precisely 0 understanding of how, since it's what I did in the first place. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Go through this for more info [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Redirect from="/:section" to="/:section/overview" />` must be inside `GeneralOverviewPage` component.

```
if(!pageName){
  return (<Redirect from="/:section" to="/:section/overview" />);
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately is redirecting me to :section/overview

Comment: @Raph117 you wont have two attributes in your route?
Than use next pattern : '/section/:section/page/:pageName'
And your url must be as test.com/section/sectionKey/page/page1.
Make correct split.