# How to set dynamic route with query params in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to set a dynamic route with query params ->  http://localhost:3000/reset-password/?id=2

```
<Route path="/reset-password/?id=:id" component={ResetPassword} />
```

But this isn't working and it's showing as page not found. Please help on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
<Route path="/reset-password/:id" component={ResetPassword} />
```

Url to visit: http://localhost:3000/reset-password/2

Answer (score 2):

1. No need for the `?id=:id`, thats part of react-router
2. You probably need the `exact` keyword;

```
<Route exact path={"/reset-password/:id"} component={ResetPassword} />
```

---

Then, in the `ResetPassword` component, use the following prop to get the `:id`;

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

---

[React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the query string.

```
<Route path="/reset-password/:id" component={ResetPassword} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-url-parameters-and-query-strings-with-react-router-fffdcea7a8e9) for query strings, but i'd recommend using params and `useParams()` hook which don't need any setup and has the same usability as shown below

```
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}


const { id } = useQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

<Route
path="/reset-password"
exact
render={(props) => <ResetPassword {...props} />}
/>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).