# React router dom's Link not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to send my user to the login page from the main page after they click login button.
But the react router dom's Link is not working and it is not redirecting to the login page.

Having issue with :

```js
 <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
```

The App.js code as well as the main page code are attached below.
So please help me out.

App.js code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import AppNavbar from './components/appNavbar';
import Login from './components/login';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import FacultyMain from "./components/facultyMain";

class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store} >
                <AppNavbar />
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/' component={FacultyMain} />
                        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The page where the link is :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button
} from 'reactstrap';
import image from '../logo.jpeg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class FacultyMain extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default FacultyMain;
```

package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "virtual-lab",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure, but try putting **exact** to the routes, like: `<Route exact path=...`

Comment: Does the URL change when you click the button?

Comment: Yes the url changes.

Comment: i think putting exact on each route may make a difference

Comment: Yea, since he has put the most general route at the top "/" it will always match without exact. @BhagyarajHaranale take a look at why **exact** is used, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836415/13830075

Comment: Thank you it worked. The problem was with the '/' path. Using exact solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the '/' path. Using exact solved it

```js
<Route exact path='/' component={FacultyMain} />
```