# React-router not redirecting to page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, switch-statement, react-router-dom

I got problem while using react-router

```
<Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact >
                         HOME 
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="/cart"  >
                        <Cart />
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="/shop/category=:category">
                        <ShoppingList />
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="/shop/category=:category/product=:title"  >
                        <ProductInfo />
                    </Route>
 </Switch>
```

As long as redirect to `/shop/category=:category` works for me, redirect to `/shop/category=:category/product=:title` doesn't shows component ProductInfo. My Link set window.location.pathname to for example: `/shop/category=Water%20sports/product=Fins`

Where the problem could be?

---

My Link is in another file, and i wrote it just

```
const productLink = "/shop/category="+Item.category+"/product="+Item.title;
...
<Link to={productLink} >
```

Comment: adding `exact` might help you. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path

Comment: nope, it doesnt helped. Still the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of your `Route`s.  React router is designed so that it send the user to the *first* route that matches their current `path`, *not* the most specific one.

When you have a path which is a subset of another path, like category/product is to category, you need to list the more specific one first.  Otherwise all category/product pages will match to the category.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact >
          HOME 
    </Route>

    <Route path="/cart"  >
        <Cart />
    </Route>

    <Route path="/shop/category=:category/product=:title"  >
        <ProductInfo />
    </Route>

    <Route path="/shop/category=:category">
        <ShoppingList />
    </Route>
 </Switch>
```