# React router automatically redirecting to /

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router

Hi I am using react router and it is not working for one page/component

ONLY working with ClientSideRouting. This issue occurs when **route typed manually or refreshed**

It is just a simple component which returns a div element. As soon as I route to that component
IT REDIRECTS ME BACK TO "/"

> Routes (**"/project/new"**)

```js
 <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/projects" component={ProjectsPage} />
        <Route exact path="/projects/:id" component={ProjectsPage} />

        <Route exact path="/project/new" component={StartProjectPage} /> // <=== ISSUE
        <Route exact path="/project/new/:id" component={StartProjectPage} />

        <Route exact path="/" component={StartPage} />
        <Route exact path="/:id" component={StartPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

> Component:

```js
import React from 'react';

const StartProjectPage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Start Project Page</h1>
        <p>Put something here</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StartProjectPage;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not enough to go on here, and no particular reason why this route would redirect you while the others do not. It would be great if you could produce a minimal working example on codesandbox or JSFiddle etc which demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Can you give me a way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: i believe this: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool
and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path
should help you... 
probably drop the "exact" for the routes without ":id", maybe order them around a bit...